Break down LSP, mason, and cmp configs into separate files
I've configured my LSP, Mason, and CMP all in a single file, but now I'd like to separate them into individual files to keep things more organized. I attempted to do this myself by splitting them into three separate files: lsp-zero.lua, mason.lua, and cmp.lua.
However, since I made these changes, it seems like things are broken. My language servers don't appear to be installed properly, autocompletion suggestions are missing, and overall, I've lost some of the functionality that was working before with Neovim.
This is my lsp-zero configuration: repo
I’d appreciate it if someone could help me get everything working again. Additionally, if you have any suggestions or feedback on my setup, I’m open to hearing them.
lsp-zero.lua:
return {
  {
    'VonHeikemen/lsp-zero.nvim',
    branch = 'v3.x',
    dependencies = {
      'neovim/nvim-lspconfig',
      'hrsh7th/cmp-nvim-lsp',
      'hrsh7th/nvim-cmp',
      'L3MON4D3/LuaSnip',
      'jose-elias-alvarez/null-ls.nvim',
    },
    config = function()
      local lsp_zero = require('lsp-zero')
      local remaps = require('bernardo.remap')

      lsp_zero.on_attach(function(_, bufnr) remaps.lsp(_, bufnr) end)

      lsp_zero.setup()
    end
  },
}

mason.lua:
return {
  {
    'williamboman/mason.nvim',
    config = function()
      require('mason').setup()
    end
  },
  {
    'williamboman/mason-lspconfig.nvim',
    config = function()
      local lsp_zero = require('bernardo.plugins.lsp-zero')

      require('mason-lspconfig').setup({
        ensure_installed = { 'typescript-language-server', 'volar', 'html', 'intelephense', 'cssls', 'jsonls', 'lua_ls' },
        handlers = {
          lsp_zero.default_setup,
          lua_ls = function()
            local lua_opts = lsp_zero.nvim_lua_ls()
            require('lspconfig').lua_ls.setup(lua_opts)
          end,
        }
      })
    end
  },
}

and cmp.lua:
return {
  {
    'hrsh7th/nvim-cmp',
    dependencies = {
      'hrsh7th/cmp-nvim-lsp', -- LSP source for cmp
      'L3MON4D3/LuaSnip',
    },
    config = function()
      local cmp = require('cmp')
      local lsp_zero = require('lsp-zero')
      local remaps = require('bernardo.remap')

      cmp.setup({
        sources = {
          { name = 'nvim_lsp' },  -- Ensure lsp source is enabled
          { name = 'nvim_lua' },
          { name = 'luasnip', keyword_length = 2 },
          { name = 'path' },
          { name = 'buffer', keyword_length = 3 },
        },
        formatting = lsp_zero.cmp_format(),
        mapping = cmp.mapping.preset.insert(remaps.cmp(cmp)),
      })
    end
  }
}

This is my lazy.lua:
local lazypath = vim.fn.stdpath("data") .. "/lazy/lazy.nvim"
if not vim.loop.fs_stat(lazypath) then
  vim.fn.system({
    "git",
    "clone",
    "--filter=blob:none",
    "https://github.com/folke/lazy.nvim.git",
    "--branch=stable",
    lazypath,
  })
end
vim.opt.rtp:prepend(lazypath)

require("lazy").setup({
  -- plugins
  require("bernardo.plugins.telescope"),
  require('bernardo.plugins.lua-line'),
  require('bernardo.plugins.treesitter'),
  require('bernardo.plugins.lsp-zero'),
  require('bernardo.plugins.cmp'),
  require('bernardo.plugins.mason'),
  require('bernardo.plugins.autopairs'),
  require('bernardo.plugins.alpha'),
  require('bernardo.plugins.formatting'),
  require('bernardo.plugins.copilot'),
  require('bernardo.plugins.copilot-chat'),
  require('bernardo.plugins.nvim-comment'),
  require('bernardo.plugins.gitsigns'),
  require('bernardo.plugins.mason'),
  require('bernardo.plugins.fugitive'),
  require('bernardo.plugins.minifiles'),
  require('bernardo.plugins.color-picker'),

  -- themes
  require("bernardo.plugins.rose-pine"),

  -- sporadic
  require('bernardo.plugins.vim-be-good'),
})


"Additionally, if you have any suggestions or feedback" - this is actually something the SE format is not very good for. It's best to focus on one question. You may still get feedback, anyhow.

@Friedrich, thanks for the info. I used to like asking that type of thing on Reddit, but I don't really like that place much. You know anywhere else where a 'ranting' would be possible?
